# Red background highlight for flagged posts - what does it mean?

Tags: support, flag-history

Hard to phrase, so here a screenshot. I thought maybe it is related to topic being deleted. But found that only 1 of those 3 red ones were actually deleted. It does not seem to be related to votes. So what does it mean?

As proposed, grey-ish red background should indicate posts were deleted. Here is my example:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224612/undo-ftp-file-overwrites - page not found
- ["Provider Load Error" when deploying SharePoint 2010 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503928/provider-load-error-when-deploying-sharepoint-2010-solution/8417739#8417739) - page exists
- [Why do I have to call SetLink()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123489/why-do-i-have-to-call-setlink/8417020#8417020) - page exists

> [image]

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean

Comment: @Bart: as I said, only 1 of 3 were deleted. Is it a bug then?

Comment: No bug; the first red one is a question, so you won't see anything when clicking it. But the last two are *answers*, so you can click them and you will still see the question and the other answers - but you won't see the *deleted* answers.

Comment: You flagged the answers. Are those still there?

Comment: @Bart: I cannot remember everything I flagged. Could be those 2 were answers, as Andrew pointed out. I don't think it's consistent to mark a question link as deleted if the question was not deleted.

Comment: If you look to the right you will see "answered" before the date. That indicates the posts were answers. The colouring suggests that the flagged post has been deleted. Nothing inconsistent about that.

Comment: @Bart: now it makes more sense to me. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: Red backgrounds on flag means a spam flag, which I'm not seeing on your screenshot. You may want to change your title, or explain what you mean.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ: does it make a difference for the purpose of this question? If yes, please take a screenshot, paste into Paint, pick a color of highlight and analyze it, you get RGB(227,217,217), which in fact is more red than it is purple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That means those posts have been deleted. That's the same background you would see if you could see the posts themselves.

For the two you say are not deleted; are you sure that the *answer* has not been deleted? (the question itself would still remain visible). If you look at the three entries, you can see the first 'red' one is a question (so you won't see anything upon clicking to view it), but the last two are *answers*... so you would still see the question upon clicking the link.

EDIT: From your links now posted, I'm exactly correct: The last two are deleted answers. When you click the link, you are going to the *question* page... but you'll find the answers in question no longer exist. (10k users can still see them as deleted)

Comment: Only 1 of 3 were found to be deleted. Does not it mean they were later undeleted and the color stayed?

Comment: @Neolisk Do you have links to those three?

Comment: @ajax333221 Yup; I just edited my answer to reflect something like that.

Comment: I edited the question to include links, but it seems you already figured it by yourself. So if something I flagged was deleted, if would show red background *on the question*?

Comment: @Neolisk No. It shows a red background on the link title. Answers don't have their own titles - they use the question's title. They also don't have their own pages - they are shown on the question's page.

Answer (score 1):

Between those posts that in the screenshot have the title with a different background, the first is a question ("Undo FTP file overwrites?"). You know it because on the right side, you read, "Asked 15 hours ago," not "Answered Dec 7 '11 at 15:21."

If you are not a 10K user on Stack Overflow, the first link will return you a 404 error page, where you can read the question "was voluntarily removed by its author," or "was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation." The other links, which are for answers, take you to the question page; you will not see the deleted answers because you are not a 10K user.

In any case, the posts that in your flag history have the title shown with a different background are deleted posts, visible only to 10K users, and moderators.